# The argument type 'Padding' how to solve this problem?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to solve this problem. I'm new user flutter please anyone help me.

```
    lib/screens/main.dart:93:26: Error: The argument type 'Padding' can't be assigned to the p
    arameter type 'String'.
     - 'Padding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/f
    lutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart').
                      label: Padding(
                             ^
    lib/screens/main.dart:108:26: Error: The argument type 'Padding' can't be assigned to the
    parameter type 'String'.
     - 'Padding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/f
    lutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart').
                      label: Padding(
                             ^
    lib/screens/main.dart:120:24: Error: The argument type 'Text' can't be assigned to the par
    ameter type 'String'.
     - 'Text' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutt
    er/lib/src/widgets/text.dart').
                    label: Text(""),
                           ^
    lib/screens/main.dart:130:26: Error: The argument type 'Padding' can't be assigned to the
    parameter type 'String'.
     - 'Padding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/f
    lutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart').
                      label: Padding(
                             ^
    lib/screens/main.dart:145:26: Error: The argument type 'Padding' can't be assigned to the
    parameter type 'String'.
     - 'Padding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/f
    lutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart').
                      label: Padding(
                             ^
    /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dar
    t:276:17: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'Bu
    ildContext'.
     - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/p
    ackages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inh
    eritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
            context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieControllerProvider)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie_audio-1.0.0+1/lib/src/chewie_pla
    yer.dart:101:17: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the cl
    ass 'BuildContext'.
     - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/p
    ackages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inh
    eritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
            context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieAudioControllerProvider)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * Where:
    Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
    > Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to
    get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 16s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      77.7s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hi Mehedi Hasan , Accept my answer if you found it helpful

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to give your widget a Padding type instead of a String
Try this

```
Padding(
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
   child: YourWidget(
         label: "a string"
   )
)
```